Replacing incoming webhook connector in teams for airflow notifications post retirement of o365
I have recently heard that the incoming webhook connector  present inside Microsoft teams is going to retire soon.
In that case , I would be interested to get answers to three questions :

How are we supposed to airflow notifications on teams?
What is the complexity level involved in the migration from incoming
webhook connector?
Do we need to make any changes to the existing codes that we made
for incoming webhook connector earlier for teams notifications?

I am hoping to receive some solutions and step by step procedure of migration from incoming webhook connector to the new tool.

Below blog explains Why are we retiring Office 365 connectors? and how do you transition from Office 365 connectors to Workflows?
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/retirement-of-office-365-connectors-within-microsoft-teams/

Microsoft has extended the retirement timeline through December 2025 to provide ample time to migrate to another solution such as Power Automate, an app within Microsoft Teams, or Microsoft Graph.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/retirement-of-office-365-connectors-within-microsoft-teams/


You need to use MS Power Automate Flows to achieve your current solution to be working. None of connector will work after 1st of October. You can still use current connectors until that date. Until 15th of August there is possibility to create new connectors, but it will be waste of time.
Depend on solution, more different connectors and different channels means more work. My pure code solution is still ongoing, and I am on it from last week.
My all cases needed to be modified so I assume you also need to do that. I prepared one structure and using for all calls. Documentation what you need is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/teams/?tabs=text1#microsoft-teams-webhook


Ok @Gediminas  Baura .Thanks a lot for your answer. I am beginning to learn  that migrating  to MS Power Automate Flows will not only need us to make changes in the codebase, but is  also going to cost us a few bucks  !!

No problem at all @AaryanOhekar, if you are stuck on anything else regarding this topic you can create new topic and tag me if need help, so far we recreated few webhooks already and solved some problems of migration. If you not owner of the code it will cost in man hours or days…

Microsoft has extended the retirement timeline through December 2025 to provide ample time to migrate to another solution such as Power Automate, an app within Microsoft Teams, or Microsoft Graph.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/retirement-of-office-365-connectors-within-microsoft-teams/
